# Value-weighted Portfolio Confusion

Tags: portfolio

just a very short question regarding value-weighted portfolios. As the results are not as expected I try to cancel out any possible wrong assumptions.

I created five portfolios à 100 companies out of the S&P500 depending on their market-to-book-value ratio. As I'm calculating value-weighted monthly returns for each portfolio I multiply each monthly returns with (MCap company/ total MCap portfolio) right? 
Thought a second about the weight on the S&P but it doesn't make sense in my eyes yet I want to be sure I'm not having a error in reasoning.

Thanks!

Comment: That's right. You divide the market value of each company by the sum of the market values of companies in your portfolio. That gives you the weight (which will be between 0 and 1).

Comment: thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, that approach gives you cap-weighted returns for value buckets.  If you actually wanted a value-weighting you could apply a fundamental weighting (eg, P/B, P/Sales) or a growth/value percentage applied to MC a la Russell Style indexes.

Comment: thanks also to you!